# Creating a fallback container/resolver DryIoc

Tags: dryioc

Current working on creating a Prism.DryIoc.Forms project to try out DryIoc (first time!).

In Xamarin.Forms there is a native DependencyService and to provide a nice way to migrate towards using Prism I would like to add it as a fallback container in case the requsted service type can't be resolved from the main container.

Current I have created a `FallbackContainer` and pass the instance of `IContainer`and overrides the methods for `IResolver` and delegates the rest of the `IContainer` calls to the instance passed during creation.

So after the default container is created and configured and then do

```
Container = CreateContainer();
ConfigureContainer();
Container.Rules.WithFallbackContainer(new DependencyServiceContainer(Container));
```

Is this the preferred method or is there any way just to attach a default `IResolver`?

Current implementation

```
public class FallbackDependencyServiceContainer : IContainer
    {
        private readonly IContainer container;

        public FallbackDependencyServiceContainer(IContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object Resolve(Type serviceType, bool ifUnresolvedReturnDefault)
        {
            return ResolveFromDependencyService(serviceType);
        }

        public object Resolve(Type serviceType, object serviceKey, bool ifUnresolvedReturnDefault,
            Type requiredServiceType,
            RequestInfo preResolveParent, IScope scope)
        {
            return ResolveFromDependencyService(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> ResolveMany(Type serviceType, object serviceKey, Type requiredServiceType,
            object compositeParentKey,
            Type compositeParentRequiredType, RequestInfo preResolveParent, IScope scope)
        {
            return new[] { ResolveFromDependencyService(serviceType) };
        }

        private static object ResolveFromDependencyService(Type targetType)
        {
            if (!targetType.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var method = typeof(DependencyService).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("Get");
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
            return genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { DependencyFetchTarget.GlobalInstance });
        }
....
}
```

Thanks and looking forward to test DryIoc since I've read it's supposed to be the fastest out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

You may directly use WithUnknownServiceResolvers returning DelegateFactory:

```
var c = new Container(Rules.Default.WithUnknownServiceResolvers(request =>
    new DelegateFactory(_ => GetFromDependencyService(request.ServiceType))));
```

No need to implement IContainer just for that.

I think it may be optimized regarding performance by replacing DelegateFactory with ExpressionFactory. But I need some time to play with the idea.

Comment: Gah managed to save the comment and then delay the edit.. Sorry.

The only point I would like to change the behavior when resolving is if the DryIoc container is unable to resolve the requested service type. The DryIoc container is used to register all framework services and also  applicaiton specific services. Will update my question with the current implementation that I believe works but feel a bit contrived since I only want the fallback behavior to ask DependencyService.GetService(serviceType) which is static

Terrible explanation I feel

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for quick response

Comment: Does DryIoc support support for resolving a baseclass when a dervied class is registered with the serviceKey? 
     Suppose class A : B {}
     Container.Register<A>(serviceKey: "A");
     Container.Resolve<B>("A");

Thanks. (perhaps this should be a new question.. Can make it one if that is better)

Comment: Managed to get it to work be resolving the base class and override using Made.Of(() => new TDerived()). This however fails if TDervied as any parameters to be injected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Container.Resolve<B>(requiredServiceType: typeof(A), serviceKey: "A"); better make it a new question in future.

Comment: Will do. Unfortunately I dont have access to the dervied type only the key...

Here is the project am integration support for DryIoc into https://github.com/joacar/Prism/tree/pr-517

Comment: Let's move to separate question.